# Rigify: change skin.stretchy_chain parent without affecting transform

Tags: rigify

In rigify, *limbs.arm* automatically allows changing the hand's parent while keeping the transform.
I'd like to extend this functionality to *skin.stretchy_chain,* but I don't know how to do this. I imagine I'd have to edit the python script or something, unless there's an equivalent in the cloudrig extension.

I'd appreciate some guidance!